Irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$
My field theory is a bit rusty, and I could use some help. We know every finite field has a unique (up to isomorphism) field extension of degree $n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It's also not hard to write down an irreducible degree $n$ polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$, that yields $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$.
What I want to understand is how to find an irreducible polynomial $f \in \mathbb{F}_{p^m}[x]$ of degree $n$. Is there an easy way to find such a polynomial? I tried to do so by starting with a degree $m$ polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, but I'm unsure how to make sure an polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}[x]$ is irreducible.
More concretely I want to find $f$ for $m = p = 2$ and $n = 3$, but I will likely have to repeat this process for other values as well, so more general advice would be great.

Duplicate question. Please use site search.
